# i am getting this error when i used searcBar from React native paper

Tags: react-native

Unable to resolve module react-native-safe-area-context from C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Projects\MealsToGo\node_modules\react-native-paper\src\components\Modal.tsx: react-native-safe-area-context could not be found within the project or in these directories:
node_modules\react-native-paper\node_modules
node_modules
11 | } from 'react-native';
12 |

> 13 | import { useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
> |                                    ^
> 14 | import useLatestCallback from 'use-latest-callback';
> 15 |
> 16 | import { useInternalTheme } from '../core/theming';

undefined Unable to resolve module react-native-safe-area-context from C:\Users\DELL\Desktop\Projects\MealsToGo\node_modules\react-native-paper\src\components\Modal.tsx: react-native-safe-area-context could not be found within the project or in these directories:
node_modules\react-native-paper\node_modules
node_modules
11 | } from 'react-native';
12 |

> 13 | import { useSafeAreaInsets } from 'react-native-safe-area-context';
> |                                    ^
> 14 | import useLatestCallback from 'use-latest-callback';
> 15 |
> 16 | import { useInternalTheme } from '../core/theming';
> at http://192.168.18.137:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:null in showCompileError
> at http://192.168.18.137:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:null in anonymous
> at http://192.168.18.137:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:null in emit
> at http://192.168.18.137:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:null in anonymous
> at http://192.168.18.137:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:null in dispatchEvent
> at http://192.168.18.137:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:null in anonymous
> at node_modules\react-native-paper\src\components\Switch\Switch.tsx:null in Switch
> at http://192.168.18.137:19000/node_modules%5Cexpo%5CAppEntry.bundle?platform=android&dev=true&hot=false&strict=false&minify=false:null in __callFunction
> at node_modules\react-native-paper\src\components\TextInput\TextInput.tsx:null in forwardRef$argument_0
> at node_modules\react-native-paper\src\components\TextInput\TextInput.tsx:null in forwardRef$argument_0

- ... 2 more stack frames from framework internals

Ijust  want to use the Searchbar from react native  paper

Answer (score 1):

If you are installing react-native-paper, then you also need to separately install react-native-safe-area-context, as per the documentation:

https://callstack.github.io/react-native-paper/docs/guides/getting-started/

Use `npm install react-native-safe-area-context`.  Then restart your application.